# How can I bulk query the Yahoo Weather API for more than one location at a time?

Tags: php, yahoo, weather

I need to load the weather for a lot of locations so I can display it on my website. What I'm doing is running an update script once an hour and caching the results of the script in a text file on my server.

But so far I have managed to retrieve only one location at a time, which is not efficient at all. I've thought about distributing the updates throughout the hour, but that's not ideal.

Is there any way how to get more locations from Yahoo in the same request? An example of what I'm looking for is:

```
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12345,43171,43411,43141
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [YQL query](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20%2a%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20location%20IN%20%2890210%2C%2012345%29):

```
SELECT * FROM weather.forecast WHERE location IN (90210, 12345) -- etc
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly somethig i needed! Yahoo documentation is terrible.. While you are helping me :) I have another problem. I want to get weather for example for Beijing in China, it is wednesday morning. But yahoo gives me Today,Wednesday,Thursday. Seems like they dont cont with timezones? or there is some trick again? thanks for help!

Comment: It's probably giving you weather for the times relative to your locale. You might try forging your locale, or you can do the timezone calculation manually using PHP's [date/time functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php).

Comment: Ok, will try rewrite the script for the query and then try the timezones. I cannot set it for one timezone as its used worldwide

Comment: Just found out another problem. The query, dunno why, is using the old ?p=2151330 so if i put the value ?w it gives me error... any idea ?

Comment: You can get weather by 2 things. 1) zip code 2) woeid number. Yahoo will soon eliminate the request by zip code and use only woeid. But if i execute the SQL its giving me the old one: ..../?p=2143 while it should giving me .../?w=fefese, so i cannot put woeid number in the yql command...

Comment: Ah, gotcha. It looks like they haven't updated that table for that change yet. Maybe contact them directly and see what they recommend.

Comment: auch thats not good... I try this: select * from weather.forecast where location in (select postal from geo.places where woeid=2151330)but it doesnt recognize the post code...